# Pythagorean Triples using points on the circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, pythagorean-triples

It's given a circle with center $(0,0)$ and radius $1.$ There are four points on the circle (see the graph). How to form Pythagorean triples using these points?
I assume that I have to use Inscribed Right Angle Theorem or Distance Formula.

And how to identify another point on the circle to form 3,4,5 Pythagorean triple?
[image: Graph]

Comment: So if you have a Pythagorean triple of integers $a,b,c$ with $a^2+b^2=c^2$, then values like $(a/c, b/c),(-b/c,a/c)$ will be points on the circle (8 points per triple, with ordering and sign variations). Here's how to [generate triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For point $A$ $\left(-\frac{15}{17},\frac{8}{17}\right)$ for example, you know from the distance formula that
$$\left(-\frac{15}{17}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{8}{17}\right)^2 = 1^2$$
so
$$\left(-{15}\right)^2 + \left({8}\right)^2 = 17^2$$
or equally
$$8^2 + 15^2 = 17^2$$
and so $(8,15,17)$ is a Pythagorean triple. A similar process of multiplying up the denominators produces triples for the other given points

Now the reverse process of identifying points on the circle given a Pythagorean triple should be clear. $(3,4,5)$ can for example produce a point like $\left(\frac{4}{5},\frac{3}{5}\right)$.